# About the behaviour of ibeacons when app is in background or killed from background?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios9

I am using Ibeacon Template example, in that i am using local notifications.when app is not in background **"didExitRegion"**,**"didEnterRegion"** and **"didRangeBeacons"** methods are getting called randomly. I don't have a clear idea on how these methods will work both when in background and killed from background, can anyone please assist me on this.Thanks in advance.

This is sample code i am using:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
      [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
      [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
      NSLog(@"You exited the region.");
      [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:@"You exited the region."];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"You entered the region.");
    [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:@"You entered the region."];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    NSString *message = @"i am in 3 meters.";
   IMViewController *viewController = (IMViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
   viewController.beacons = beacons;
   [viewController.tableView reloadData];

   if(beacons.count > 0) {
      CLBeacon *nearestBeacon = beacons.firstObject;
      if(nearestBeacon.proximity == self.lastProximity ||
       nearestBeacon.proximity == CLProximityUnknown)
      {
         return;
      }
    self.lastProximity = nearestBeacon.proximity;
    NSLog(@"lastProximity: %ld", (long)self.lastProximity);
    NSInteger str=(int)nearestBeacon.accuracy;
    //NSString *distance=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance: %d",(int)nearestBeacon.accuracy];
    if (str ==3)
    {
        [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:message];
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Monitoring: actions triggered on entering/exiting region’s range; works in the foreground, background, and even when the app is killed.
Ranging: actions triggered based on proximity to a beacon; works only in the foreground. Try with this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/66584/ios7-ibeacons-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will give you answer.

If you leave the significant-change location service running and your iOS app is subsequently suspended or terminated, the service automatically wakes up your app when new location data arrives.
At wake-up time, the app is put into the background and you are given a small amount of time (around 10 seconds) to manually restart location services and process the location data. (You must manually restart location services in the background before any pending location updates can be delivered).

Because your app is in background, it must do minimal work and avoid any tasks (about 10 seconds) or it can request more background execution time using the **beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:** method of the UIApplication class

**Note: When a user disables the Background App Refresh setting either globally or for you app, the significant-change location service doesn’t launch your app.** Further, while Background App Refresh is off an app doesn’t receive significant-change or region monitoring events even when it’s in the foreground.

So app is also launched in the same case when user enters/exits region.

So remember two things

1. Turn on Background App Refresh setting.
2. use beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler if your code takes longer than 5~10 seconds.